# textarea with writing code

Tags: c#, html, asp.net

I suffer from the following there

```
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)

    <fieldset>
        <legend>Posts</legend>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Title)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Title)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Title)
        </div>


        <div class="editor-label">
            <h4>Теги:</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            <input type="text" name="tags" value="@ViewBag.Tags"/><br />
        </div>

        @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.DateTime, new { @Value = System.DateTime.Now.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss") })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.DateTime)

        <h5>body:</h5><textarea name="body" rows="10" cols="80" required >
</textarea><br />

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Avtor)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Avtor)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Avtor)
        </div>

        <p>
            <input type="submit" value="save" />
        </p>
    </fieldset>
}
```

in

```
public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include = "Id,Title,DateTime,Body,Avtor")] Posts post, string tags, string body)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            tags = tags ?? string.Empty;
            string[] tagNames = tags.Split(new char[] { ' ' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
            foreach (string tagName in tagNames)
            {
                post.Tags.Add(GetTag(tagName));
            }
            post.Body = body;
            db.Posts.Add(post);
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }

        return View(post);
    }
```

public partial class Posts

```
{
    public Posts()
    {
        this.Comments = new HashSet<Comments>();
        this.Tags = new HashSet<Tags>();
    }
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(64, MinimumLength = 1)]
    public string Title { get; set; }

    public System.DateTime DateTime { get; set; }


    [Required]
    [AllowHtml]
    public string Body { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(64, MinimumLength = 1)]
    public string Avtor { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Comments> Comments { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Tags> Tags { get; set; }
}
```

if the user dials in plain text in textarea, it's okay, but there is a need to add the code text. It makes `<pre> and <code>`but it can only do I have in the program, not the user in textarea. Strictly speaking how to do so in tehtarea could write code and save it in the database and not get an error using `<a> <script>` and that they could be seen in the text. so the spacecraft itself is implemented on this site. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Add ValidateRequest="false" to the first line, <@Page...

Comment: Wait, there's a spacecraft involved?!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `AllowHTMLAttribute`

see this [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.allowhtmlattribute%28v=vs.118%29.aspx)

This will only allow html for that specific field in your viewmodel but not the whole thing.

or alternatively you can do:

```
[ValidateInput(false)]
public ActionResult someAction(SomeViewModel model)
{
    //Your code to handle the control
}
```

EDIT: Notice that your textarea is not part of the model in your HTML, can you change that `<textarea name="body"....` line to:

```
@Html.TextArea("body", new { rows=10, columns=80 })
```

After that your body textarea element should be able to capture HTML elements to your controller.

Comment: I did not understand what to do

Comment: Is textarea body not part of your model? As I see in your code above.
Your code for partial class Post seems doing fine with the [AllowHtml] tag

Comment: I am sorry my English is bad because I can not properly understand. if the tags will also write <a> fault, I wanted to know how to make even be in one place and then have to correct others.

Comment: I'm new to c # so I can avoid stupid mistakes and do not understand the obvious.

Comment: @user3240336 This is totally fine :) I have updated my answer see if it helps you understand?

Comment: I definitely think that will not help.after at least change the error has not changed

Answer (score 1):

Create a strongly typed model to accept the data posted to the server, use the data annotation [AllowHtml](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.allowhtmlattribute%28v=vs.118%29.aspx) to accept HTML as input:

```
public class SomeViewModel
{
    Posts Post { get; set; }

    [AllowHtml]
    public string Body { get; set; }
}
```

Then change the controller to

```
public ActionResult Create(SomeViewModel model)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        model.Post.Body = model.Body;
        db.Posts.Add(model.Post);
        db.SaveChanges();
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
    return RedirectToAction("Index");
}
```

Also try adding this to the following location in your web.config file just above the pages section:

```
<system.web>
  ...
  <httpRuntime requestValidationMode="2.0" enableVersionHeader="false" />

  <pages...
  ...
</system.web>
```

Changing the request validation mode will essentially only validation pages rather than every http request. You can read more about it here on [MSDN HttpRuntimeSection.RequestValidationMode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.configuration.httpruntimesection.requestvalidationmode.aspx)

Comment: [AllowHtml] did not help

Comment: Okay, what is happening now? Is ModelState valid or not?

Comment: I changed and extracting, but "Detected a potentially dangerous value Request.Form, obtained from the client (body = "123<a>321")."

Comment: Check your web.config and what does the httpRuntime element contain? Does it looks like this? `<httpRuntime requestValidationMode="2.0" enableVersionHeader="false" />`

Comment: did not find such a line in the web.config.At least where it should be?

Comment: <system.webServer> <system.web> <appSettings> <system.web.webPages.razor> <configSections>?

Comment: I've updated the solution with the location it should be placed